# Jetpack compose text field cleared when non-compose state is read

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-button

I have a Jetpack compose form, created from [this tutorial](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/jetpack-compose-forms/). It shows errors nicely by validating the form when you click the submit button. I want the button on my form to be dynamically enabled, using the same form state.

The issue is that `state.requiredFieldsNotEmpty()` appears to reset the mutable state text variable whenever it is called. Meaning typing does nothing because it's instantly cleared. Why? All it does is read the state variable, no writing. Specifically calling this line `field.text.length < it.length` triggers the bug and clears field.text.

Relevant code:

```
        val state by remember {
            mutableStateOf(FormState())
        }

        Column {
            Form(
                state = state,
                fields = listOf(
                    Field(name = "pan",
                        placeholderHint = R.string.card_number,
                        validators = listOf(Required(), MinLength(length = Constants.MINIMUM_PAN_LENGTH))),
                )
            )

            Row {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = { if (state.validate()) submitData(state.getData()) },
                    enabled = state.requiredFieldsNotEmpty(),
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.confirm),
                    )
                }

            }
        }
```

Form.kt:

```
@Composable
fun Form(
    modifier: Modifier,
    state: FormState,
    fields: List<Field>) {
    state.fields = fields

    Column(modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)) {
        fields.forEach {
            it.Content(modifier)
        }
    }
}

class FormState {
    var fields: List<Field> = listOf()
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }

    fun validate(): Boolean {
        var valid = true
        for (field in fields) if (!field.validate()) {
            valid = false
            break
        }
        return valid
    }

    fun requiredFieldsNotEmpty(): Boolean {
        for (field in fields){
            if(field.validators.contains(Required()) && field.text.isBlank()){
                return false
            }
            val minLength = field.validators.find { it is MinLength } as MinLength?
            minLength?.let {
                if(field.text.length < it.length){
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    fun getData(): Map<String, String> = fields.map { it.name to it.text }.toMap()
}
```

Validators.kt

```
sealed interface Validator
open class Email(var message: Int = emailMessage) : Validator
open class NotExpired(var message: Int = expiryMessage) : Validator
open class Required(var message: Int = requiredMessage) : Validator
open class MinLength(val length: Int, var message: Int = minLengthMessage): Validator
```

Field.kt

```
class Field(
    val name: String,
    val placeholderHint: Int = R.string.empty,
    val error: Int = R.string.empty,
    val singleLine: Boolean = true,
    val keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    val validators: List<Validator>
) {
    var text: String by mutableStateOf("")
    var supportingError: Int by mutableStateOf(error)
    var minLength: Int by mutableStateOf(-1)
    var hasError: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)

    private fun showError(error: Int) {
        hasError = true
        supportingError = error
    }

    private fun showMinLengthError(error: Int, length: Int) {
        hasError = true
        minLength = length
        supportingError = error
    }

    private fun hideError() {
        supportingError = error
        minLength = -1
        hasError = false
    }

    @Composable
    fun Content(
        modifier: Modifier,
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(value = text, isError = hasError, supportingText = {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = supportingError))
        }, singleLine = singleLine, keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions, placeholder = {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = placeholderHint),
            )
        }, modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp), onValueChange = { value ->
            hideError()
            text = value
        })
    }

    fun validate(): Boolean {
        return validators.map {
            when (it) {
                is Email -> {
                    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(text).matches()) {
                        showError(it.message)
                        return@map false
                    }
                    true
                }

                is Required -> {
                    if (text.isEmpty()) {
                        showError(it.message)
                        return@map false
                    }
                    true
                }

                is NotExpired -> {
                    val month = text.substring(0, 2).trimStart('0').toInt()
                    val year = text.substring(2, 4).trimStart('0').toInt()
                    val now = LocalDate.now()
                    if ((year < now.year) || (year == now.year && month < now.monthValue)) {
                        showError(it.message)
                        return@map false
                    }
                    true
                }

                is MinLength -> {
                    if (text.length < it.length) {
                        showMinLengthError(it.message, it.length)
                        return@map false
                    }
                    true
                }
            }
        }.all { it }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach to validation could use polymorphism, this would improve the code quality (but probably not help with your bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the following issues with the original code:

1. The form fields *themselves* were never remembered (and so the nested state properties would be replaced with new ones on every render)
2. The `Required` class had reference semantics, so `field.validators.contains(Required())` would never match
3. The computation of `requiredFieldsNotEmpty()` depended on state (due to the declaration `var text: String by mutableStateOf("")`), but was not wrapped in `derivedStateOf`

The following adjustments:

```
sealed interface Validator
open class Email(var message: String = EMAIL_MESSAGE): Validator
data class Required(var message: String = REQUIRED_MESSAGE): Validator
open class Regex(var message: String, var regex: String = REGEX_MESSAGE): Validator
open class MinLength(val length: Int, var message: String = MIN_LENGTH_MESSAGE): Validator
```

```
@Preview
    @Composable
    fun Screen(){
        val fields = remember {
            listOf(
                Field(name = "username", validators = listOf(Required(), MinLength(length = 3))),
                Field(name = "email", validators = listOf(Required(), Email()))
            )
        }

        val state by remember { mutableStateOf(FormState()) }
        val buttonEnabled by remember { derivedStateOf { state.requiredFieldsNotEmpty() } }

        Column {
            Form(
                state = state,
                fields = fields
            )
            Button(
                enabled = buttonEnabled,
                onClick = { if (state.validate()) toast("Our form works!") }) {
                Text("Submit")
            }
        }
    }
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Nice one thank you this is the missing piece, I find it confusing to wrap your head around the fields themselves being remembered across compositions

Comment: Yeah, well, I guess the proper way to think about those things is when you see code like `val stuff = new Whatever()` inside a compostable function, this is no Compose magic, it's just regular Kotlin code, so the data *will* of course be recreated each time the function is called. You actually *need* the Compose magic for it to behave *otherwise*